# Cocos2d fix sprite on screen?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

example fix sprite on top_right

```
ShowLabelScore = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"showscore.png"];
ShowLabelScore.position = ccp(515,300); < top right
[self addChild:ShowLabelScore];
```

but move tiles game

self.position = ccp(self.position.x+50,self.position.y); << layer move

layer move but not want to move the menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create layer for menu and Gamescene layer. Add your current layer and menu layer in gamescene, or you can just create Gamescene layer and add your menu items and current layer in it. after this move only your current layer